# Defining String with the char '{' in JAVA

Tags: java, string, special-characters, declaration

I'm trying to define a Constant with some pattern identifier to be able to replace it in large String constructs later, for example in a complex Querie.

```
private static String SUBSTITUTE_1 = "${substitute1}";
```

But when I do that, compiler complains about expecting a number next to the '{' char.

My question is: Is there a way to escape the special characters in the string?

```
private static String SUBSTITUTE_1 = "\$\{substitute1\}";
```

This does not work.

This is strange because if I define a String builder like so

```
private static String SUBSTITUTE_1 = new StringBuilder("${substitute1}").toString();
```

there no problem with the special characters.

Unless there is something really obvious that i'm missing this does not make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [There is nothing wrong with your first declaration](https://ideone.com/29HWEz). The compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: Indeed - place post a [mcve]. My guess is that you're potentially using this in a regular expression, and that it's an execution-time error rather than a compile-time error, but we can't tell at the moment.

Comment: I'm using Intellij Comunity Edition. Maybe a bug.

Comment: I think that's unlikely. But if you post a complete example, including the *exact* error message rather than a reinterpretation of it, that would really help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Intellij's compiler detects that somewhere in the code I'm using the defined constant in a `String.replaceAll()` instruction and complains about its definition as `"${x}"` is not a valid Regex Expression.

Solution is change to `String.replace()`.